# python3 C extension nosetests

Tags: c, python-3.x, nose, python-c-extension

I have written some C extensions for my package, when I test the package with unit test, there is no error, however, when I use nose tests, there is error complaining

```
*** Error in `python3': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002111800 *** Aborted (core dumped)
```

So far, I know my C extension has memory leakage problem(not solved yet), but I haven't found any memory overrun problem.

My question is how should I debug it? BTW, any related suggestions are welcome.

Here is the package: https://github.com/1a1a11a/mimircache/tree/develop

Comment: Run it on Valgrind?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The C extension itself runs fine on Valgrind, but the together with python, it will generate a lot of errors, the suppress file seems not working well under python3 @Kevin